# how to compare value in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to compare 2 values under some conditions.

If  `$(".value1").text()` and `$(".value2").text()` start with `"v"`, then check whether
number of `$(".value1").length` (in this case 0.1)) < `$(".value1").length` (in this case 0.4)

```
<div class="value1">v0.1</div>
<div class="value2">v0.4</div>
```

First, I want to check whether the value of the div starts with `"v"`, then I want to compare the value after the `"v"`.

How would I do that and how would the syntax look like?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: More specifically, are you trying to do version comparison?  so `1.0` and `0.5` would say that `v1.0` > `v0.5` ?  You're mentioning length and I'm not sure if you REALLY care about the length, or if you're doing version comparison.  Also, what about multi-part versions, e.g. `v1.5.2.5` as is common for versioning?

Comment: `$(".value1").length` is *not* `0.1`, it's `1` (because there is only 1 DOM element in the jQuery object).

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to compare some versions. As I'm not that familiar with JS I never thought about a way to compare the version itself. I just thought about the numbers behind the text. Length can be wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var value1 = $('.value1').text();
  var value2 = $('.value2').text();

  if (value1.indexOf('v') == 0 && value2.indexOf('v') == 0) {
    var version1 = parseFloat(value1.substring(1), 10);
    var version2 = parseFloat(value2.substring(1), 10);
    if (version1 > version2) {
      document.write(value1 + ' > ' + value2);
    }
    else if (version1 < version2) {
      document.write(value1 + ' < ' + value2);
    }
    else {
      document.write(value1 + ' == ' + value2);
    }
  }
```

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Kncf4/

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest doing some reading on the various `String` methods available to you in JavaScript.

In this case, you want [`charAt`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.4) (to find out whether the 0th character is a "v") and [`substring`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.15) (or [`substr`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.2.3)) to get just the part after the `v`. Then you'll want [`parseFloat`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.3) to turn it into a number. Or, as [bad syntax points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13458063/157247), you *could* use a regular expression (although I wouldn't do precisely what he/she's done if you do, I'd look to go further with it), but that may be more complicated than necessary.

The links above are to the specification, but it can be hard going. There are lots of books and websites available for learning the basics of JavaScript. [Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript) is a decent reference website.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how one would get string data from elements, cast it to an integer, and compare it. http://jsfiddle.net/svcH9/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // get elements
    var v1 = $('.value1').text(),
        v2 = $('.value2').text();
    // check requirements
    if (isVersionString(v1) === true && isVersionString(v2) === true) {
        // replace the v and cast to float
        v1 = getVersion(v1);
        v2 = getVersion(v2);

        // test
        $('body').append(v1).append(v2);

        // simple compare
        if (v1 < v2) {
            alert('Value two is greater than value one');
        }
    }
});

function isVersionString(value) {
    return /^v[0-9\.]{0,}$/.test(value);            
}

function getVersion(value) {
    return parseFloat(value.replace('v', ''), 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex solution:

```
var val1 = $.trim($(".value1").text());
var val2 = $.trim($(".value2").text());
var hasV = (/^v/.test(val1) && /^v/.test(val2));

if (hasV) {

    var num1 = parseFloat(val1.replace(/v/, ''));
    var num2 = parseFloat(val2.replace(/v/, ''));

    if (num1 < num2) {
        alert('yes');
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to explain why this is overkill?

Comment: @ badsyntax: Using regex for such simple manipulation. I mean seriously, `val1.replace(/v/, '')` instead of `val1.substring(1)`?

Comment: @ badsyntax: Like I said, overkill. Using something more complicated than necessary to do the job. Anyway, not worth getting into a discussion...

Comment: Agreed, it's opinionated. I see no problem with using simple regex for simple string manip.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in regards to using replace vs substring, wouldn't one think that representation of what it's actually doing is better than assuming the first character? And in terms of maintainability, if there were to be a case without "v" or a case with more characters, a new method would have to rewrote anyways.

Comment: @MattLo: The code was ensuring "v" was the first character earlier, no assumption.

Comment: @ badsyntax: If you're going to fire up the regex engine, at least *use* it: `var m = /^v([0-9.]+)$/.exec(val1); if (m) { num1 = parseFloat(m[1]); ...` :-) *(Of course, that expression isn't perfect, but you get the idea...)*

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I seriously don't know what you are trying to say to me.

Comment: @badsyntax: I'm saying use a simple tool to do a simple job. Or, if you're going to use a complex tool, get the most out of it. A point worth one comment, not a whole stream of them, things rather went pear-shaped there. :-) Best,